# JavaScript formula to convert WGS84 lat, long values to RD_New co-ordinates

Tags: coordinate-system, javascript, epsg, angular

I have a requirement in my project to convert WGS84 GPS format co-ordinates to RD_New co-ordinates

```
WGS84(E,N): 51.998929,4.375587
RD(X,Y):    85530,446100
```

I see some online tools and Proj4 js libraries to so this conversion. But I need some formula so I can directly convert values in my Angular project.

Below link converts from RD_New to WGS84.
http://www.aukema.org/2020/02/convert-dutch-rd-coordinates-to-wgs-84.html

I couldn't find formula for RD_New conversion

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Projection code often involves some pretty heavy trigonometry. It probably isn't wise to code this from scratch in the JS application, when you can use a servlet or other projection-aware code library to do the work for you.

Comment: I have gone thro proj4js library for this. Is there any arcgis API to do this conversion

Comment: See https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-projection.html

Comment: You will have to implement 2 sets of formula--1) a 7-parameter coordinate frame/position vector transformation between WGS 84 and Amersfoort (which RD New is based upon) and 2) Stereographic (sometimes called double stereographic). [EPSG Guidance Note 7-2](https://epsg.org/guidance-notes.html) has the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EPSG Code for RD_New seems to be EPSG:28992. See https://epsg.io/28992 .

If you really, really don't want to use proj4js you could use the MapTiler coordinates API, see https://docs.maptiler.com/cloud/api/coordinates/ .

Using proj4js is very simple.

You define your coordinate system (the definition string is from epsg.io)  as

```
proj4.defs("EPSG:28992","+proj=sterea +lat_0=52.1561605555556 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +towgs84=565.4171,50.3319,465.5524,1.9342,-1.6677,9.1019,4.0725 +units=m +no_defs +type=crs");
```

WGS84 is already defined.
Then you just need to get your input lat and lon, plug that into the proj4() function, as follows:

```
var r = proj4("WGS84", "EPSG:28992", [4.375587, 51.998929]);
```

Note the coordinate order is [lon, lat].

The result is an array with two elements:

```
[85372.55908145086, 446034.99013433844]
```

See jsfiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/zf4rL97b/

Comment: Thanks. is there any formula for this conversion so that it can be handled in code itself, without going for pro4js library ?